# FPGA - Push button constraints

Tags: constraints, fpga, timing

Is there any benefit/reason to apply a setup & hold constraint to a push button input to an FPGA when the button is asserted asynchronously?

From what I understand a violation can still happen regardless as the button can be pressed within the setup and hold time of the flip-flop that it's connected to inside the FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

Push buttons generate very slow changing signals compared to the system clock (0.001 .. 10Hz vs. several MHz). Applying setup/hold times is a waste of effort. Just apply a timeing ignore rule.

A propper synchronizer and maybe a debouncer circuit is needed anyway.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that there are no constraints valid as the input is truly asynchronous?

Comment: Yes. You can't name a frequency, a toogle propability, a pulse width, a relation to another signal  (e.g. a phase to a clock), ... So apply a timing ignore and tell your STA that it can spare the calculations for that pin/path.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous poster that push button input pin shouldn't be timed (use false_path).  If you want to be very safe, you should probably:

1. Turn on Schmitt trigger for the input pin connected to the button.
2. Feed the input signal through 2 stage synchronizer (2 flops in serial)
3. Implement debouncer either using analog circuit on the board, or doing this digitally using a counter after the synchronizer.